# Override controller in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: css, overriding, prestashop

My override is not working

I tried to add a custom.css the safe way to our default bootstrap theme. I followed this tutorial:

http://www.prestadb.com/prestashop-override-controllers-tutorial/

The difference to 1.6 should be that the file should be placed in:

/override/controllers/front

instead of

/overrides/controllers/

In the first mentioned directory I have a file called FrontControllerCore.php with following content:

```
<?php
class FrontController extends FrontControllerCore
{
    public function setMedia()
    {
        parent::setMedia();   
        $this->addCSS(_THEME_CSS_DIR_.'custom.css');  
    }
}

?>
```

But the custom.css is not loaded, I do not see it in the source code of the frontend. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ahh my fault I found it!

The name of the file should be FrontController.php and for this to be loaded, you have to manually delete the cache/class_index.php file!

Comment: I could load the css this way, but I cannot override existing classes. Any clues on how I can do that?

Comment: @PabloTapia use the ` !important` rule

Answer (score 3):

if you need to simply add a custom.css to a theme you can create a custom.css file in:

```
/themes/my_theme/css/autoload/custom.css
```

instead of override the controller

Comment: This is the best method, in my opinion. Prestashop is already looking in that folder, allowing you to write your custom code and not worry about caching.

Comment: and easier to maintain!