# override "src" controller back office in prestashop

Tags: symfony, overriding, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Firstly, I tried all the questions & answers related to this topic. Additionally and I tried related questions and try to solve it but no success. So please read my question thoroughly.

**i refer below Link this topic but not getting solution**

[override-core-files-using-module-prestashop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49947782/prestashop-1-6-override-admin-controller-not-overriding)

[override-controller-in-prestashop-1-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472036/override-controller-in-prestashop-1-6)

[prestashop-translating-overrided-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616964/prestashop-translating-overrided-controller)

[prestashop-1-6-controller-override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086802/prestashop-1-6-controller-override)

i want to this override prestashopbundle  controller using my custom module.

**my Custom module structure**

```
 - mymodule
      - controllers
         - admin
           - prestashop
      - override
      - views
```

**i want to this controller override**

```
prestashop/src/prestashopbundle/controller/Admin/sell/Customer/CustomerController.php
```

**mymodule path**

```
module/mymodule/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***After Long Time research in Prestashop after then i got best Solution***

**Prestashop(1.7.*) say :**

> As Controllers are not available for override and can be regarded as
>   internal classes, we don’t consider moving a Controller in another
>   namespace as a backward-compatibility break.

[Controller and Routing](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/architecture/migration-guide/controller-routing/)

***After i created a custom Hook register my custom Module. inside custom hook implement functionality and DONE it :)***

```
 public function hookActionViewCustomers($params)
    {
        $creddit = Configuration::get('Credit_Checkbox_1');
        $customerid =$params['request']->attributes->get('customerId');
        $Status_HTMl =$this->Get_Status_HTML($customerid);
        if(!$creddit)
        {
            // Checkbox Checked
            $ButtonDisable =" <button type=\"submit\" disabled='disabled' title='Not Allow'> Check Status </button>";
        }
        else{
            // Checkbox unChecked
            $ButtonDisable =" <button type=\"submit\" title='Click Get Status'> Check Status </button>";
        }
        return $Status_HTMl.$ButtonDisable;

    }
```